# Is there a way to inject a method into clojure.core at lein repl startup?

Tags: clojure

the :injections keyword is really useful. However, I am hoping to dynamically install a couple of functions in core for debugging purposes. How can this be done?

```
    :injections [(require 'spyscope.core)
                 (use '[cemerick.pomegranate :only (add-dependencies)])
                 (use '[clojure.tools.namespace.repl :only (refresh)])]
```

Ideally, I would want `refresh` to stay around to that I can use it everywhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `intern` for this purpose, although I suspect there might be a better way to have debugging functions available all the time. I've used `intern` with `clojure.core` the times that I wanted to mess around with existing functions to learn stuff, but injecting functions in other namespaces feels too hackish.

```
(intern 'clojure.core 'refresh (fn [] (println "refreshed!"))
(ns another-ns)
(refresh)
;=> refreshed!
```

And in your `project.clj` you can use the [`:repl-options`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L294) key, specifically [`:init`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L304). This, though, depends on the workflow you have in mind, since the function will not be available in all the namespaces that already exist when the REPL fires up, because they all have already `refer`ed the public vars in `clojure.core`.

You could however, call `(clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh)` once, when the REPL starts, to get all namespaces reloaded and then the function should be available from then on. I just tried the following and it seems to work:

```
:repl-options {:init (do (require 'clojure.tools.namespace.repl)
                         (intern 'clojure.core 'refresh clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh)
                         (clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh))}
```